# iterator in template class

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I have the following template class.

```
template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator = equal_to<_Type> >
class CSearch
{
...
};
```

It should store STL stuffs like list, set or string.
I store all elements (for example strings) in private class member:

```
map<int,_Type> seqs;
```

Now I want to use iterator, but there is a problem with <_Type>::const_iterator.

```
template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator>
void CSearch<_Type,_Comparator>::Foo1(int id, const _Type & needle)
{
seqs.insert(make_pair(id,needle));

for(_Type::const_iterator it=seqs[0].begin();it!=seqs[0].end();it++)
cout<<*it<<" ";

cout<<endl;
}
```

or analogically

```
 for(map<int,_Type>::const_iterator it=seqs.begin();it!=seqs.end();it++)
 cout<<*it<<" ";
```

Comment: "but there is a problem with <_Type>::const_iterator" -- *What problem?*

Comment: "there is a problem". Great. Fancy exploring it? Then explaining it to us? Otherwise, pal, I'm afraid you're just a [_help vampire_](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)!

Comment: probable duplicate of [some question I really can't be bothered to dig up](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

`<_Type>::const_iterator` is a dependent type.

Refer to it as `typename <_Type>::const_iterator` instead.